# How do I turn this into a stencil?

Tags: painting

I want to make a stencil of this image.

[image]

Comment: Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

1. Print it onto some thick paper
2. Grab a knife and cut out the black areas

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing #3.

Comment: I did think that, but the question was 'how do I make a stencil', not 'how do I use it' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cutting a stencil occasionally leaves un-attached "islands" that require "tabs" to hold the part in place.

For example: To make a stencil of "O" requires some means to keep the counter (centre) of the letter in place to mask the whole shape against filling in solid.
Here's the full list:
1. Transfer the pattern to thick paper
2. Grab a knife and cut out the black areas
3. Leave tabs to hold the islands in place.

[How to Make Stencils ***with Islands***](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Stencils-with-Islands/)

The Instructables.com had such a great tip for holding the islands in place using a paper clip that I couldn't resist passing it along. I wish it was my idea. It isn't; but, here it is.